# How to really delete a key of a .json in python

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I make a discordbot and I want to delete key (channel id) and value (message id) of a .json file but I've this error:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\baron_btjit4i\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\baron_btjit4i\Desktop\Autrebot\Cogs\ticket.py", line 213, in on_raw_reaction_add
    data.pop(str(channell.id))
KeyError: '932014068682858507'
```

My json file like this:

```json
{"931966019612864623": "931966020808228922", "931979274074869811": "931979274884354048", "931981646561943603": "931981647354667058", "931982921231912971": "931982922058186803", "932003079451213894": "932003080352989203", "932010872006664212": "932010872790999140", "932014068682858507": "932014069953753098"}
```

And my code is there:

```py
with open(msg_start, 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    if channell.id in data:  # channell.id = 932014068682858507
        data.pop(str(channell.id))

with open(msg_start, 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: The error message says that you first converted the channel id to a string when you tried to delete it. Did you also convert the channel id to a string when checking if the dictionary contains it?

Comment: No, I've send my code and I used it

Comment: But the code line from the error message `data.pop(str(channell.id))` is nowhere in the code snippet

Comment: Hey, sorry, I deleted str()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
with open(msg_start, "r+") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
    data.pop(str(channell.id), None)
    data_file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, data_file)
    data_file.truncate()
```

Comment: it don't work sorry

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there isn't error ;-;

Comment: Is it possible that the keys in the json file are integers and not strings? If this is the case, you must not convert the channel id into a string. So the third line should look like this: `data.pop(channell.id, None)`

Comment: that doesn't work either. But again there is no error message.

Answer (score 1):

When loading a json python convert it to a dict so just delete by key and dump again. I will do with loads and dumps because is more simple but works for you reading a file too, just make sure you read the reference:

```
import json

values = '{"931966019612864623": "931966020808228922", "931979274074869811": "931979274884354048", "931981646561943603": "931981647354667058", "931982921231912971": "931982922058186803", "932003079451213894": "932003080352989203", "932010872006664212": "932010872790999140", "932014068682858507": "932014069953753098"}'
data = json.loads(values) # convert json to dict

type(data) # <class 'dict'>    

del data["931966019612864623"]
ob = json.dumps(data)  # convert to json

print(ob)
# '{"931979274074869811": "931979274884354048", "931981646561943603": "931981647354667058", "931982921231912971": "931982922058186803", "932003079451213894": "932003080352989203", "932010872006664212": "932010872790999140", "932014068682858507": "932014069953753098"}
```

Reference  [JSON.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)